# Craft 2: New locale introduction not affecting old entries

Tags: entries, localization, settings

I just introduced a new (2nd) locale to my site. It now seems I can easily set up translated versions for "single" and "channel" pages that I set up new.

The *old entries*, which existed **prior to introducing the new locale**, are not translatable however:

The little (green) dot after the language switch in these entries’ individual editor is only a grey circle instead of a green one like with the newly setup pages. If I click the new language I get a native "Page not found" error.

I have set the specific legacy pages to be fully translatable though in the Sections settings, set them to be available in both locales but I get the feeling that **Craft is not able to handle "legacy" singles & entries that were introduced during a one-locale setup of the page, is that correct?**

Is there any way of working around the hassle of having to delete all the pre-multi-locale pages and re-setting them up to have them available in both locales (which would solve my problem but is a pain with so many pages/entries)?

Comment: I'm assuming this is for Craft 2?  Did you enable the locale for the sections you are having problems with? https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/localization-guide.html#step-2-update-your-sections  Probably worth verifying the rest of the steps in that guide as well.

Comment: Everything was setup correctly and now it seems to work fine. I suppose the task for translating the pages was stuck or something, so I didn’t see the translations until some voodoo happenend in the background an hour later or so, flushing whatever pipeline there might have been.

Comment: Fair enough... would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it might help someone in the future?

Comment: Will do so, currently still running into 404s with the new locale, so I want to make sure first there is no overlap between these problems.